# Unable to open phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache, wampserver

I am trying to open my phpMyAdmin through wamp server but I am getting an error:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

I have changed the **phpMyAdmin.conf** file to

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside # replace the lines # # Order Deny,Allow # Deny from all 
# Allow from 127.0.0.1 
# 
# by 
# 
# Order Allow,Deny 
# Allow from all 
# <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/"> 
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
      AllowOverride all 
      Order Deny,Allow 
      Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

still facing the same error .

Comment: @mitkosoft This is Windows

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running

Comment: @mitkosoft my root directory is same as mentioned above i.e c drive.

Comment: I am using wamp 5.4.3 version  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Do you have an `Alias....` line above what you show us?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, my bad, agree

Comment: There is no such thing as WAMPServer 5.4.3

Comment: @rishabhagarwal which version of Apache you are running?

Comment: no i cannot see any Alias.... im my myphpAdmin file

Comment: let me paste the whole code of the file       Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all
# Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: for Apache 2.4 you must use `Require all granted` istead of `Order allow, deny` and `Allow from all`.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment this line

```
# <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
```

by removing the `#`

and change the version number to match

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
```

> That version of phpMyAdmin is not one that was released with any version of WAMPServer I can remember, so are you trying to manually upgrade phpMyAdmin

Also it is safer assuming you are not actually wanting the universe to be allowed into your server not to use `Allow from all`

You could try changeing that to

```
Allow from localhost, 127.0.0.1
```

And if I remember correctly Apache 2.2.22 was IPV6 aware so you could also add

```
Allow from ::1
```

Then the server would only allow connections from the PC running WAMPServer, very relevant as we are talking about phpMyAdmin.

If you want it to be accessible from other PC's on your network you can also add

```
Allow from 192.168.1
```

For example, assuming you are on that subnet, any ip on that subnet would be allowed access

> Once you make any of these changes, remember you must restart Apache for them to take effect.

```
wampmanager->Apache->Service->Restart service
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? 2.2 or 2.4

Comment: Are you getting access now?

Comment: thank you very much now this solution of yours is working for me with allow from localhost,127.0.0.1